# Центровка текста на стринце

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      Одна из двух колонок
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Одна из двух колонок
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

почему оно не на середине страницы?

Comment: Что именно должно быть на середине страницы?

Comment: Блоки должны стоять по средине

Comment: Они и стоят по середине. А текст идёт слева на право в блоке.

Comment: А чтобы макет был адаптивен под все устройства достаточно указать col-md-4 или нужно для всех? col-xs и тд?

Comment: Добавьте класс bg-info к колонкам для наглядности.

Comment: Он уже адаптивен. На всех устройствах будет выполняться правило  класса col-md-4. Выставляйте классы в зависимости от нужного вам правила расположения блоков.

Answer (score 0):

Ширина и расположение колонок меняется в зависимости от ширины страницы.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12  bg-info col-sm-4 col-lg-6">
      Одна из двух колонок
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 bg-success col-sm-4 col-lg-6">
      Одна из двух колонок
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```